# FullCalendar can't click button in day cell

Tags: fullcalendar

In fullcalendar I'd like to have a clickable button in each day's cell. However, when prepending an element in the cell, the button is covered by a table that lives on top of it, preventing clicks.

code:

```
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    events: [{
      start: new Date(),
      editable: true,
    }],
    dayRender: function(date, cell){
        $el = $('<a href="http://www.google.com">click</a>');
        cell.prepend($el);  
      }
})
```

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/XL1FU7LbJx5ZNpighaFB?p=preview)

Comment: There is a way to click through elements when you have the following CSS [`pointer-events: none;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)

Comment: That did it but I had to set the individual events in the calendar to `pointer-events: all` after making that change. [code](http://plnkr.co/edit/nMclQpxLz0sv0AkgFZiH?p=preview)

Comment: @WillIAM You have resolved this situation?

Comment: Has no other solution been found for this? I can't believe setting pointer-events is the only way to bypass this and I don't know why it was designed this way in the first place.